# Eigenspinor of helicity of electrons

Tags: particle-physics, dirac-equation, spinors, helicity

I am reading the chapter in Griffth's introduction to elementary particle.

By solving the momentum space Dirac equation and requiring the solution of the spinor to be the eigenspinor of the helicity operator, see the questions below.

[image]

I worked out the math but I don't understand the solution completely. For example,
If $p_x = p_y = 0$ and $p_z =  |\bf{p}|$, it implies that the eigenspinor $u^{(-)}$ does not exits, similarly for the case of $u^{(+)}$ with $p_z =-|\bf{p}|$.

Since helicity is the dot product of momentum and spin operator, does it implies that the spin of an electron cannot point in the direction exactly opposite to its momentum?

Comment: why do you think it doesn't exist? Could it be that you simply plugged in the numbers and got zero divided by zero? try using $\vec{p} = p_z \hat{z} + p_x \hat{x}$ and taking the limit $p_x \to 0$ to see that everything stays well-define (or using L'Hospital's rule)

Comment: Because the components are proportional to $ \sqrt {|p|- p_z} $, I think it does not need L'Hospital rule

Comment: see that for $\vec{p} = p_z \hat{z} + p_x \hat{x}$ with the limit I suggested you get $|p| - p_z \simeq p_x^2 / 2|p_z|$ and taking the square root of this is linear in $|p_x|$. So $N p_x$ would be finite in this limit

Comment: \Isn't that $N u_A \approx (|p| - p_z )/\sqrt{|p|-p_z} \approx \sqrt {|p|-p_z} $?

Comment: $u_A$ has two components. The upper one is indeed zero in that limit. The lower one, however, is $N(u_A)_2 \propto p_x / \sqrt{|p|-p_z} \propto \sqrt{2|p_z|}$ which will be proportional to unit after taking care also of the $\sqrt{|p|}$ in the denominator

Comment: Thank for your answer, but the even the lower component you mentioned should be $\approx \frac{ |p| (p_z-|p|)} {\sqrt{ |p| (p_z-|p|)}} = \sqrt{ |p| (p_z-|p|)}$

Comment: For instance, why you got the $p_x$ cancel?  I got $p_x^2 / \sqrt{|p|-p_z}$ instead of $p_x / \sqrt{|p|-p_z}$ forget about $|p|$, I must have a factor of $\sqrt{(p_z-|p|)}$

Comment: I'll write the answer in detail. This is becoming a bit long for the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are taking too literally the zero divided by zero as something undefined, where in this case it is just a form of writing the solution. You can start with $p_x=p_y=0$ and solve everything from the start, or, more conveniently, take a limit where $p_x \to 0^+$ and see that everything behaves properly.

Let us assume that $p_z > 0$ and take $\vec{p} = p_z \hat{z} + p_x\hat{x}$. We can expand everything to leading order in $p_x$, for the case of $u_A^-$. We get that $|p| = \sqrt{p_z^2+p_x^2} \simeq p_z + \frac{p_x^2}{2p_z}$ and then

$$ N = \sqrt{\frac{E+mc^2}{2|p|c(|p|-p_z)}} \simeq \sqrt{\frac{E+mc^2}{2p_z c}} \sqrt{\frac{2p_z}{p_x^2}} =   \sqrt{\frac{E+mc^2}{c}}\frac{1}{p_x}$$
where we omitted terms that diverge slower than $1/p_x$. And then we get

$$N u_A = N\begin{bmatrix}|p|-p_z\\p_x\end{bmatrix} \simeq \sqrt{\frac{E+mc^2}{c}}\frac{1}{p_x} \begin{bmatrix}p_x^2/2p_z\\p_x\end{bmatrix} \to \sqrt{\frac{E+mc^2}{c}} \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

where we took the limit $p_x\to 0$ at the end. So indeed $u_A^-$ has a spinor representation that we associate with spin down, which makes sense for a particle going in the positive $z$-direction ($p_z>0$) and has negative helicity.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! so happy to notice the mistake I made.